# @keyframes animation not working on Safari (macOS, iOS)

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

I have a words swipe animation code which works perfectly on Google Chrome but doesn't on Safari.
I mean the first sentence works, but if you want to see the others then you have to click where the animation is in order to make them appear.

Here's the CSS:

```
.random-facts-container {

.random-facts-header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "RooneyPro-Medium";
  font-size: 35px;
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 5rem 0;
}

.factsCarousel {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;

  .facts {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 65px;

    h2 {
      background: linear-gradient(271deg ,#a0e9ff 30%,#a162e8 50%,#f093b0 70%,#edca85 94%);
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      font-family: "RooneyPro-Bold";
      letter-spacing: -0.5px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 48px;
      padding-bottom: 3rem;

      ul {
        padding: 0;

        li {
          height: 45px;
          margin-bottom: 45px;
          display: block;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

.flip8 {
  -webkit-animation-name: flip8;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
  -webkit-animation-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1.2);
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: flip8;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1.2);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flip8 {
  0% { margin-top: -720px; }
  6.25% { margin-top: -630px; }
  12.5% { margin-top: -630px; }
  18.75% { margin-top: -540px; }
  25% { margin-top: -540px; }
  31.25% { margin-top: -450px; }
  37.5% { margin-top: -450px; }
  43.75% { margin-top: -360px; }
  50% { margin-top: -360px; }
  56.25% { margin-top: -270px; }
  62.5% { margin-top: -270px; }
  68.75% { margin-top: -180px; }
  75% { margin-top: -180px; }
  81.75% { margin-top: -90px; }
  88% { margin-top: -90px; }
  94.25% { margin-top: 0px; }
  99.99% { margin-top: 0px; }
  100% { margin-top: -720px; }
}
```

}

I tried adding @-webkit- before keyframes but still doesn't work. I tried also to use the whole percentage and with whole numbers, no result.

https://jsfiddle.net/timdavhen/39dgehr7/5/

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `margin`, `padding` and position properties (`left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`) in animations. It's a bad influence and causes freezes and lags. Always use `transform: translate`.